# trouble matching pattern against querystring for mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have two urls in my project that I am trying to translate using `mod_rewrite`:

- `hall/booking_message.php?booking_id=11` > `hall/booking_message/11`
- `hall/venues.php?city=delhi&city_value=1&locality=mehrauli&locality_value=82` > `hall/venues/city/delhi/city_value/1/locality/mehrauli/82`

So far, I have the following in `.htaccess` which works for `hall/booking.php?hall_id=5&booking_date=2014-10-23&session=Morning`
and `hall/description_banquethall.php?hall_id=5` but not for the two URLs listed above:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hall/

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?city=([^&\s]+)&city_value=([^&\s]+)&locality=([^&\s]+)&locality_value=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?city=$2&city_value=$3&locality=$4&locality_value=$5 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?hall_id=([^&\s]+)&booking_date=([^&\s]+)&session=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3/%4? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?hall_id=$2&booking_date=$3&session=$4 [L,QSA]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?id=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?hall_id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/? [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?id=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?hall_id=$2 [L,QSA]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?id=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?booking_id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/? [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?booking_id=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?booking_id=$2 [L,QSA]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: You should use a PHP framework like CakePHP or Codeigniter for this task, writing all routes in .htaccess is a cumbersome process.

Comment: You already have a rule that handles `hall/venues/city/delhi/city_value/1/locality/mehrauli/82` isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

put this link in your .htaccess and then check your link hall/booking_message/11

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([.*]+)/([.*]+)/?$ $1.php?booking_message=$2&booking_id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It doesn't answer OP's requirement as there is no `booking_message=` parameter in OP's question. OP wants internal URL as: `/hall/booking_message.php?booking_id=11`

Comment: this rule is not working RewriteRule ^(.*)/([.*]+)/([.*]+)/?$ $1.php?booking_message=$2&booking_id=$3 [L,QSA] and i want my url like hall/booking_message/11

Comment: i translate my one url like hall/booking_message/11 by using same rule RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?booking_id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?booking_id=$2 [L,QSA]